# Child control blocking parent's event handler

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a user control which has a registered MouseDown eventhandler. The user control has a ScrollViewer with an ItemsControl and a TextBlock. The visibility of the ItemsControl and TextBlock is toggled by the MouseDown eventhandler so at a time only one of them is visible. The eventhandler is invoked correctly when I click the TextBlock but not in the ItemsControl.

If I set the "IsHitTestVisible" on the ItemsControl to false the view's eventhandler gets exposed but I'm not able to scroll.

Can someone suggest a way out please?

Code is somewhat like this:

```
<Grid>
 <Border>
  <ScrollViewer>
   <TextBlock>
  </ScrollViewer>
 <Border>
 <Border>
  <Grid>
   <ItemsControl/> <!-- Has a ScrollViewer in template to show scroll bar -->
  </Grid>
 <Border>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your UI scenario sounds kinda strange to me, but if you still want to implement it then you can do the following. You are not getting event raised for the paren becaus ItemsControl marks it as handled, so it is not [routed further](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx). You can subscribe to [PreviewMouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown.aspx) event instead of MouseDown in the parent. Then no matter what the parent will receive notification before it's children.

**UPDATE**

You can do the following

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid MouseDown="HandleMouseDown">
        <TextBlock />
        <ItemsControl IsHitTestVisible="false"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

So you will have scroll for text block and for items. ItemsControl's own scroll bars will not be used.

**UPDATE 2**

If you want to have separate ScrollViewers, then another possibility can be the following (although I think some of borders and grids are really unneeded. Only if they are functional in your snippet)

```
  <Grid>
    <Border>
      <ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock MouseDown="HandleMouseDown">
      </ScrollViewer>
    <Border>
    <Border>
      <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
          <Grid MouseDown="HandleMouseDown">
            <ItemsControl IsHitTestVisible="false"/>
          </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
      </Grid>
    <Border>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that as soon as I touch the scrollbar on the ItemsControl the event handler is invoked. I can only scroll the ItemsControl using the mouse wheel.

Comment: @Krishter: so you want to behave one way when content of ItemsContol is clicked and another way when it's scrollbar is hit? If so, I see only a way of using separate ScrollView.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you find it strange?

Comment: @alpha-mouse: I've added a code snippet to the question. The TextBlock and ItemsControl are toggled using data binding. I don't understand where you're suggesting I add a scrollviewer.

Comment: Hmm. I wasn't able to visualize how these controls disappearing on mouse click can look friendly to user. But now I see, how it can be useful. I'll edit my answer for possible solution.

Comment: @alpha-mouse : There was a reason why I did not use the independent scrollviewer outside. However on furthur googling, I found this. What do you think?
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/9584c459-89e1-4d0c-92a5-73fed4b92810

Comment: @Krishter: this is another possibility you can try.